# ffmpeg audio using lame

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming, lame

I have installed ffmpeg from source with --enable-libmp3lame.

Now when I run ffmpeg with:

```
sudo ffserver -f ffserver.conf & ffmpeg -s 320x240 -f video4linux2 -i /dev/video0 http://localhost:7070/feed1.ffm
```

I get this output:

```
[8] 23814
ffmpeg version N-54962-g8720d3a Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Aug  1 2013 11:25:27 with gcc 4.7 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.7.2-2ubuntu1)
  configuration: --enable-libmp3lame
  libavutil      52. 40.100 / 52. 40.100
  libavcodec     55. 19.100 / 55. 19.100
  libavformat    55. 12.102 / 55. 12.102
  libavdevice    55.  3.100 / 55.  3.100
  libavfilter     3. 81.103 /  3. 81.103
  libswscale      2.  4.100 /  2.  4.100
  libswresample   0. 17.103 /  0. 17.103
Input #0, video4linux2,v4l2, from '/dev/video0':
  Duration: N/A, start: 77666.594680, bitrate: 36864 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: rawvideo (YUY2 / 0x32595559), yuyv422, 320x240, 36864 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 1000k tbn, 1000k tbc
Missing audio stream which is required by this ffm
[8]+  Stopped                 sudo ffserver -f ffserver.conf
```

How do I specify the webcam audio stream?

Answer (score 1):

Your ffmpeg command only outputs video. You need to generate a blank audio:

```
ffmpeg -s 320x240 -f video4linux2 -i /dev/video0 -f lavfi -i aevalsrc=0 \
-c:a libmp3lame http://localhost:7070/feed1.ffm
```

Another weird thing in your command line is that you don't encode video. I assume you don't want raw YUV video to be streames, right?